# Filling Button with a Radio Button

Tags: html, css, button, parent, fill

I was wondering whether it is possible to fill a parent button with a radio button and remove the default radio button styling, keeping the radio button functionality for the button.

```html
<button>
  <input type='radio' />
</button>
```

Comment: Why. What is the usecase?  You can use JavaScript to set a hidden field when the button is clicked

Comment: Basically I am using Formik and Yup for input validation and need three separate radio buttons to select an input (wont work with buttons)

Comment: Show the HTML and what it needs to do and we  have a better idea. What is the problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: I just need a radio button (in a button as shown in the snippet) to fill an outer button styling.

Answer (score 0):

Hopping this is the desired behavior, this is my solution:

```css
button input[type="radio"] {
  /* Add if not using autoprefixer */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* For iOS < 15 to remove gradient background */
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Not removed via appearance */
  margin: 0;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <input type='radio' />
</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as a radio button as its hidden in the DOM, thanks anyway.

Comment: I've answered to your question. You didn't mention what kind of functionality you need.

Comment: Should have worded the question better, I need it to work as a radio button, but thanks for your reply, upvoted :)